# Jquery, getting DIV ID as it is being dragged using "draggable"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I found another post about this but the solution there isn't working for me... I am trying this (having already instantiated the draggable option separately:

```
 $( ".masker" ).bind( "drag", function(event, ui) {

  testdragging =    ui.draggable.attr('id') ;


});
```

Just calling this: ui.draggable.attr('id') ; makes the entire class of DIV not draggable, if I simply remove this then it works fine, just can't figure this out, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) (not viewing it from the *droppable* side) it's [`ui.helper`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) instead of `ui.draggable`, like this:

```
$(".masker").bind("drag", function(event, ui) {
  testdragging = ui.helper.attr('id');
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/znu6e/).

Comment: Thanks! will try that, I was worried I wouldn't be able to get it